# MongoDB get limited, evenly spaced documents within date range

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection of documents which are readings from a group of sensors.
The documents have the date of the reading, the reading itself, and the id of the sensor.

I need to be able to return some of these documents in a date range in order to graph them in a user facing program. I know how to get documents in a date range, but if the range is big enough there could be a lot of documents returned, let's say 1000. Limiting the returned documents to, say 100, would only return the first or last 100 documents. Is there any way to return the documents spread across the date range?

I don't want to randomly select documents up to the limit, because that would make the graph inconsistent for each request.

Comment: Have you checked out [$bucket](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/)?

Comment: If I'm understanding what `$bucket` is, and how to use it. I would, for my example of a 100 doc limit, create 100 buckets of date intervals, and take the first doc from each to get the data to graph? Also looking at the Mongo docs, would `$bucketAuto` be a better fit?

Comment: Yes, you can use [$bucketAuto](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/) if you don't want to define how the splits should occur. However, you would either need to do it with no granularity set or convert your dates to timestamps before using $bucketAuto. _"Available only if the all `groupBy` values are numeric and none of them are `NaN`."_

Comment: Whether picking `$bucket` or `$bucketAuto` would depends on your actual scenario and mostly will lead to opinion-based answer.